# Prepared Statement to Insert and update different table in database

Tags: php, mysqli-multi-query

Please How can i use prepared statement to update one table and insert into another table. i did what i no was right but the when i submit the form on that page, it just give me a blank page and nothing happened in the two database see what it look like

```
$check = "INSERT INTO users(userEmail, password, joinDate, recEmails,
                            isActive, hash, lastUpdated) 
            VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), 1, 0, ?, NOW() ) ";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($check);
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$emailAddy,$password,$hash );

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$check1="UPDATE pin SET status = '1', usedby = ?,WHERE pin = ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($check1);

$stmt->bind_param('ss',$emailAddy,$pin);                
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The result i get is this example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
I have tried and discovered that the issue is hidden somewhere here, if i remove the update table instruction the code works fine but one i return the issue comes back. Please can anybody help?

Comment: Where do you set the values to `$emailAddy`, `$password`, `$hash`, `$emailAddy` and `$pin`?

Comment: Why is your code always so oddly formatted, you can have more than one thing on a line you know. And indentation, indicted subordination, this is fall through code and should all start with the same indent

Comment: i declared them in functions and called for it in the signup page

Comment: sorry about that RiggsFolly

Comment: Please reformat your questions instead of asking a duplicate question. I've flagged your original question for deletion since this one's gotten an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error here:

```
$check1 = "UPDATE pin SET status = '1', usedby = ?, WHERE pin = ?";
```

Change it to (Remove the `,` after `usedby = ?`)

```
$check1 = "UPDATE pin SET status = '1', usedby = ? WHERE pin = ?";
```

Comment: Thanks Alon Eitan That solved it didn't know how i ignored that.